# How promising is the engineered bs-bnAb as an HIV-1 therapeutic intervention?

Tags: treatment, hiv, cure

I found that a lot of sites talk about this news: a research team from Hong Kong university invented a universal antibody drug for HIV-1 and they tested that in mice [news source](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2018-05-team-universal-antibody-drug-hiv-.html).

Basically, they propose *an engineered tandem bispecific broadly neutralizing antibody (bs-bnAb) as an innovative product for HIV-1 prophylactic and therapeutic interventions.*

How promising is this recent research?

Comment: The study does exist and is [available here](https://www.jci.org/articles/view/96764). I'm interested to hear what others think about the significance of this study. But the researchers themselves point out: *It should be noted that HIV-1–infected humanized NSG-HuPBL mice do not fully represent infected patients, although this model has been widely used to study bnAb-based HIV-1 immunotherapy* To me, this seems more like a new direction of research than anywhere near to a drug.